# Fastest way to convert string into list of tuples

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, eval

I have millions strings of the form

```
"[(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8)...]"
```

which I need to convert into python lists containing tuples. I've discovered `eval` (which is bad and slow) and `ast.literal_eval` which is a little faster, but am looking for something a bit faster if it exists. Unfortunately, using `json.loads` doesn't work for me since the strings aren't technically valid JSON due to the parentheses.

Comment: Are the millions of strings just line by line? Do you want a list of lists of tuples stored in one variable in the end? Have you considered just removing the "" using regex?

Answer (score 1):

`json.loads()` cannot understand tuples, but can understand arrays `[]`. 
I don't know this is the optimal method, but can be used to solve the problem.

The trick here is to replace `(` by `[` and `)` by `]`.

```
import json

data = "[(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]"

data = data.replace("(", "[")
data = data.replace(")", "]")

data = json.loads(data)

tuple_list = []
for t in data :
  tuple_list.append(tuple(t))

print(tuple_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how accurate ipython timeit magic method is, but the following result seems good enough:

```
In [28]: s = "[(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8)]"

In [29]: %timeit l = eval(s)
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.4 µs per loop

In [30]: %timeit l = ast.literal_eval(s)
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.2 µs per loop

In [31]: %timeit l = [tuple(x) for x in json.loads(s.replace('(', '[').replace(')', ']'))]
The slowest run took 6.04 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.8 µs per loop
```